# How can i add <p> tags to wrap contact form 7 response message?

Tags: html, wordpress, forms, google-tag-manager, contact-form-7

I am implementing the new tag manager update on a contact 7 form. It works adding some attributes to the `div` containing the response message. My problem is that the text of the response must be wrapped inside `<p>` tags and those tags must also be wrapped by the `div`.

[- This is the `div` before submitting the form:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3POIO.png)

`<div class="wpcf7-response-output" aria-hidden="true"></div>`

[- And this is the same `div`after the form is submitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwdEI.png), Note that the values of the attributes of the `div` are changed for privacy issues.

```
<div class="wpcf7-response-output" aria-hidden="true" data-gtm-vis-recent-on-screen-99999999_9="9999999" 
data-gtm-vis-total-visible-time-99999999_9="100" data-gtm-vis-has-fired-9999999_9="1" data-gtm-vis-first-on-screen-999999_9="9999999" › Su mensaje se ha enviado con éxito. Muchas gracias. </div>
```

[- This is what a need (edited in chrome dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrYu7.png)

```
<div class="wpcf7-response-output" aria-hidden="true" data-gtm-vis-recent-on-screen-99999999_9="9999999"
data-gtm-vis-total-visible-time-99999999_9="100" data-gtm-vis-has-fired-9999999_9="1" data-gtm-vis-first-on-screen-999999_9="9999999" >
<p>
Su mensaje se ha enviado con éxito. Muchas gracias.
</p>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please post all code necessary in text form to the question itself. Images don't count.

Answer (score 0):

You can try innerHTML.

```
<div class="wpcf7-response-output" aria-hidden="true"data-gtm-vis-recent-on-        
screen-99999999_9="9999999" 
data-gtm-vis-total-visible-time-99999999_9="100" data-gtm-vis-has-fired- 
9999999_9="1" data-gtm-vis-first-on-screen-999999_9="9999999"> 
Su mensaje se ha enviado con éxito. Muchas gracias. 
</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.querySelector(".wpcf7-response-output").innerHTML = 
    "<p>Su mensaje se ha enviado con éxito. Muchas gracias. <p/>";
    }
</script>
```